# Show a binary code does not exist.

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

Show that there is no $(6,9,3)$ binary code.

I'm pretty sure the way to tackle this problem is to deal with it's generator matrix and then get a condradiction.  However I seem to be getting no contradiction and I'm unsure if this is even the right approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this supposed to be 64 bits with 9 data bits and minimum distance 3? Or do you mean (9,6,3)?

Comment: The code isn't necessarily linear, so you can't talk about the generator matrix.

Comment: Previously: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314645/is-there-a-6-9-3-2-code